# OnClick add a row with data from database laravel/js

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have an invoice and I want to add many items. I have a row with a select and two input fields. Select takes data from DB(it takes all items that are on the database) and input fields are for price and quantity.

I have a button Add Item that I want to add another row with specific inputs. My problem is with select because I do not know how to get data from the database to appear in options.

I am displaying the first line with Laravel while at the click of a button I am trying to implement it with JS. I also want to show the price of the selected item depending on the quantity.

```
<table id="items_table">...</table>

<button id="add_item">Add Item</button>

<script>
let counter = 1;
const items = {!! json_encode($items->toArray()) !!}

$('#add_item').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    const select = document.createElement('select')

    for(let i = 0; i< items.length; i++){
       const opt = items[i]
       const el = document.createElement('option');
       el.textContent = opt.name;
       el.value = opt.id;
       select.appendChild(el);
    }

    const newRow = jQuery(
        select +
         counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
         counter + '"/></td></tr>');
     $('#items_table').append(newRow);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add only relevant code, properly indent your code and try to use modern code conventions before asking - this _really_ helps when answering.

Comment: 1) Are you getting any errors in the log? 2) What does the _rendered_ output look like (including the rendered "items" variable)? 3) What are you attempting to do with `jQuery(select + counter + ...)` -- here "select" looks like it's an element, but everything else is just string concatenation

Comment: It really looks like there is some code missing before your `newRow`

Comment: No this is all the code. 
1)No I am not getting any error but this code is not working.
2)Items returns an array of objects with data from database
3) I am just trying to create a new row with Select(with data from items variable) and two input fields

Comment: did my answer help at all? Is this still an issue? - Note that I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting your data types mixed up. You are creating the select element with `document.createElement('select')` - that returns a HTMLSelectElement and then you are trying to use that as if it was a String. Here is what your issue really is:

```
const select = document.createElement('select')
console.log(select + "<br>");
// This prints out "[object HTMLSelectElement]<br>"
```

To solve the issue, you must convert the select to a string of HTML, try something like this

```
const select = document.createElement('select')
select.innerText = "Test";
const selectAsHTML = select.outerHTML;
console.log(selectAsHTML + "<br>");
```